# Mutate_at stops when it cannot interpolate a group, tryCatch does not work

Tags: r, syntax, interpolation, na, dplyr

I have data as follows:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- structure(list(country = c("Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "Germany", 
"Germany", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", 
"UK", "UK", "UK", "UK", "UK"), year = c(2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 
2004, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004
), a = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1000, NA, 1600, NA, 1000, NA, 
1000, NA, NA), b = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1000, NA, 2200, 
NA, 1000, NA, 1000, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```

I am trying to interpolate some values.

I was trying to recreate this error (Which is of course a very logical error, because there is no data for Germany):

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `a`.
x need at least two non-NA values to interpolate
i Input `count` is `(structure(function (..., .x = ..1, .y = ..2, . = ..1) ...`.
i The error occurred in group 123: value = "group", country = "Arthur", State = "Nebraska".
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

With the following code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(zoo)
st_example %>%
  group_by(country) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(a),~na.fill(.x,c(NA, "extend", NA))) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(a))
```

I am regretfully not getting the error I expected.

My problem is that when `mutate_at` fails, it does not go on with the next group. I have tried to built a `tryCatch` around `mutate_at(vars(a:b),~na.fill(.x,c(NA, "extend", NA))) %>%`  but was unsuccessful.

How do I tell `mutate_at` to continue if it encounters an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is being thrown by `zoo::na.fill`, not `mutate_at()`. Running `rlang::last_error()` from the console would have surfaced this.

```
zoo::na.fill(c("hello",NA), c(NA, "extend", NA))
Error in approx(wix, unlist(object[wix]), xout = wrng) : 
  need at least two non-NA values to interpolate
```

You can hack it together with something like this:

```
DT %>%
  group_by(country) %>%
  mutate_at(
    vars(a),
    ~ tryCatch(
        as.numeric(na.fill(.x,c(NA, "extend", NA))),
        error = function(error) .x
    )
  ) %>%
  filter(!is.na(a))
```

As an aside, there is no reason to use `data.table` in the example code - `dplyr` will coerce `data.table` objects to `data.frame`.

Answer (score 1):

The following should work without the use of tryCatch():

```
DT %>%
  split(.$country) %>%
  purrr::map(~mutate(., a = as.numeric(na.fill(.x$a, c(NA, "extend", NA))))) %>%
  bind_rows()
```

Answer (score 1):

If the aim is to perform linear interpolation on column `a` by country then:

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

DT %>% 
  group_by(country) %>%
  mutate(a = na.approx(a, na.rm = FALSE)) %>%
  ungroup
```

or to interpolate all numeric columns:

```
DT %>% 
  group_by(country) %>%
  mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~ na.approx(., na.rm = FALSE))) %>%
  ungroup
```